# put-rest-api aws cli not updating endpoint description tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am trying to update my rest api via the aws cli and I don't get the results I desire. I am running the commands

`aws apigateway put-rest-api --rest-api-id XXXXXXXXXX --mode merge --body 'file://api.yaml'`

`aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api XXXXXXXXXX --stage-name latest`

However I notice that even though the endpoint was added, documentation specific things such as `tags` and `description` are not being set and so when we fetch the swagger definition from aws, these keys are omitted.

I put the yaml file I am using with the into https://editor.swagger.io/ and no problems there as well

I don't get any errors when running the above commands. I don't understand why the "merge" process is not finding the swagger keys and applying them.

Comment: It will be useful understand and troubleshoot this you provide masked or quite similar api.yaml file in this question. As well as in case you are passing more options to the used aws cli commands

Comment: the yaml was not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that not only do I need to run an update via the `put-rest-api` command but I also need to publish the documentation(did this via the AWS Console UI and it worked). I haven't found the best command to do so via the aws cli. Will make an edit when I do.

**EDIT**

I have learned that the aws cli cmd `put-rest-api` is a precursor for updating the documentation and definition of the REST API, and that the two are deployed via different commands. So I was missing the step:

`aws apigateway create-documentation-version --rest-api-id XXXXXXXXX --documentation-version test_version --stage dev`

As you may or may not know, you can only deploy documentation once so use

`aws apigateway update-stage --stage-name dev --rest-api-id tu2ye61vyg --patch-operations "op=replace,path=/documentationVersion,value=test_version"` to deploy an existing version to another stage